# Rebecca Chernoff - Real? or not?

Tags: support, spam

I got this in email from Rebecca Chernoff of stackexchange:

"I would like to send you a gift to show my appreciation, but I need some details from your first. Please supply your information at the link below and I can get that out to you as soon as possible."

Is this real or did I get spammed? I don't really care about about a tshirt although it would be kinda cool.

Comment: I am not real. (:

Comment: @RebeccaChernoff: Nobody real smiles with their head upside-down. :)

Comment: Thanks all. I now know.

Comment: AND KNOWING IS HALF THE BATTLE! (the battle against robots that is)

Comment: @RebeccaChernoff - Thanks for the T-shirt and stickers! ;~) This is real.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Rebecca Chernoff is really one of the Stack Exchange employees. They do generally collect that information via a google docs form thing.

As a moderator I received a t-shirt, some stickers, and a couple bicycles.stackexchange.com branded water bottles (Specialized Purist which are really good at not making water taste like plastic).  I'm not sure exactly what they're sending high-rep users. I'm sure they at least want to send you stickers, probably a t-shirt, but I'm not sure about water bottle(s).

[profile for Rebecca Chernoff on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&A sites http://stackexchange.com/users/flair/60791.png](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/users/954/rebecca-chernoff)

Comment: Ok. And thanks. Just checking. Cleaning out gmail and wanted to make sure that I hadn't inadvertently responded to spam.

Answer (score 5):

This is real, or at least I got the same one some time ago. It should take you to a Google form where you fill out. And I'm fairly sure Rebecca is real.

I got water bottles, but I don't remember if that was for being a high-rep user or if it was from when I was a pro-tem mod here.